# How to access CSS of a component that isn't in DOM in testing

Tags: css, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working as an intern on a component library. It don't understand much by I know the project doesn't have a app.component so it does not make an app and the component I'm trying to test is not part of the DOM. So in karma-jasmine when I do getComputedStyled() I get undefined returned. Is there a way I can add this component to the dom and retrieve the css for testing. I will put some code below for you to understand what I want.

```js
export class CheckboxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() size: 'large' | 'small' | 'tablet' = 'large';
  @Input() label: string = 'test check box';
  @Input() checked: boolean = false;
  @Input() colorTheme: 'dark' | 'light' = 'light';
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}  

  public get classes(): string[] {
    let cls:string = [];

    cls.push(this.size)
    if (this.colorTheme==='dark') {
      cls.push('dark')
    }
    if (this.error){
      cls.push('error')
    }
    if (this.disabled){
      cls.push('disabled')
    }
    return cls
  }

}
```

I want to test if the component is having proper styling when we change different inputs like size or theme. eg.

```js
it('should have 24px width for small', () => {
    component.size = 'small';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // add the component to DOM to retireve css, else getComputedStyled() returns undefined

    expect(getComputedStyle(fixture.nativeElement).width).toEqual('24px');
})
```

Comment: what is component in your test? Can you share your test setup and how your fixture is created?

Answer (score 0):

To test a component from component library you should add this component to your test bed. In your test you may add this:

```
@Component({
    template: `<your-checkbox-component-selector>TEST</igx-avatar>`
})
class InitCheckboxComponent {
    @ViewChild(CheckboxComponent , { static: true }) public checkBox: CheckboxComponent;
}
```

Then in `beforeAll` in your test you compile the test component like this:

```
beforeAll(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            CheckboxComponent,
            InitCheckboxComponent
        ],
        imports: []
    })
        .compileComponents();
}));
```

Then in test you will have access to your component:

```
it('should have 24px width for small', () => {
    const checkBoxUnderTest = fixture.componentIns
    checkBoxUnderTest.size = 'small';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Add your expects here
}
```